# Decomposition of a matrix with orthogonal columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Note that this question is also posted in [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414999/decomposition-of-a-matrix-with-orthogonal-columns). I'm new to the community so I'm also posting this here if it is more appropriate.

---

I am given a square matrix $A = [A_1, A_2, ..., A_n]$, where columns $A_i$ are orthogonal to each other. In another word, $A = OD$, where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The target is to decompose $A$ into a product of two matrices of the same type. That is, $A = X_1X_2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both named 'xxx'.

('The same type' here just means that we can classify them into one specific category. I know this is pretty vague, but I didn't come up with a better explanation. E.g, we can decompose $A = O \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a scalar, as a product of two Jacobian matrices of conformal maps. But this is still a special case of $A$.)

For example, if we consider a special case of $A$ as an orthogonal matrix (i.e., $D = I$), one can simply decompose $A$ as a product of two orthogonal matrices. However, this is a very limited case. I am wondering whether there is a general decomposition of $A$?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks to @BenGrossmann for making the question clearer: I'm looking for some "type of matrix" such that if $P$, $Q$ are matrices of this type, then $PQ$ will necessarily have orthogonal columns.

Comment: QR decomposition factors a matrix A into Q orthogonal and R upper triangular.

Comment: It feels like there might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) lurking here. What question are you trying to answer by expressing $A$ as a product of two matrices "of the same type"?

Comment: @The Red Thanks for your comment. Yes, you are right. At the same time, orthogonal and upper triangular is not 'of the same type'. Of course, they could both belong to a wider category, e.g., full-rank. I'm wondering whether there is a decomposition that both matrices are of the same relatively specific type.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann, Thanks for the reminder. I'm trying to make an assumption for a type of matrices $B$ that the product of two matrices of the same type, i.e., $\hat{B} \tilde{B}$, has orthogonal columns. This is a key step of proof in an ongoing work.

Comment: @kwu I'm not sure I understand. It seems you're looking for some "type of matrix" such that if $P,Q$ are matrices of this type, then $PQ$ will necessarily have orthonormal columns. Is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, you are right. One thing that is a little different is that $PQ$ will have *orthogonal* columns, but not necessarily orthonormal. Because $PQ$ can have columns of any norm ($PQ = OD$, where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix).

Comment: @kwu I misspoke there, I meant to say orthogonal. In any case, that clears things up a bit. Honestly, I don't think that there is a type of matrix more general than the orthogonal matrices (i.e. $P$ and $Q$ have ortho**normal** columns) that will have this property.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks and I've edited my question accordingly. Yes, the most 'general' type of matrix that I can think of is the jacobian of a conformal map, i.e., $P = O \lambda$. I'm struggling to find a more general case since it apparently leads to a special case of $A$.

Comment: I am thinking Cholesky decomposition also.But I am not sure.Both LL’ matrices are diagonal and require A matrix to be positive definite

Comment: @TheRed Thanks for your help. Actually, Ben Grossmann's way to put it is better than mine. It's more like composition rather than decomposition.